# Using LINQ to fill a boolean with true or false based off of condition

Tags: c#, sql, linq, left-join

I am performing a linq query to grab some data from the DB.

Here is my linq:

```
   var requests = (from job in db.JobRequest
                        join jobCode in db.Job on job.JobCode equals jobCode.PkJobCode
                        join jobParams in db.JobRequestParameter on job.PkJobRequestId equals jobParams.FkJobRequestId into jobRequestParameters
                        from jobParams in jobRequestParameters.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new Objects.JobRequest.JobRequest()
                        {
                            JobRequestId = job.PkJobRequestId,
                            JobType = job.FkJobType,
                            JobCode = job.JobCode,
                            Schedule = job.Schedule.AddMilliseconds(-job.Schedule.Millisecond),
                            IsRunning = job.Running,
                            Description = jobCode.BriefDescription,
                            HasParams = ???
                        }).ToList();
```

The main 2 tables I am concerned with here are **JobRequest** and **JobRequestParameters**...

**JobRequest** table has 13 records (but not all jobs have parameters).

**JobRequestParameters** table only has 4 records. They are joined on by *PkJobRequestId*. **JobRequestParameters** has a *pkJobParameterId* IF and only IF the *PkJobRequestID* from the **JobRequest** table has parameters..

How can I modify this linq query to be similar to the SQL I have written below. I would like to be able to fill HasParams with a true if the pkJobParameterId exists, and a 1 if not. Below is my SQL

```
        SELECT 
      job.pkJobRequestId,
      jobParams.pkJobParameterId,
      (CASE
        WHEN jobParams.pkJobParameterId IS NULL THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
      END) AS HasParams
    FROM
      Job.JobRequest job INNER JOIN
      Reference.Job jobCode ON job.JobCode = jobCode.pkJobCode LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      job.JobRequestParameter jobParams ON job.pkJobRequestId = jobParams.fkJobRequestId
```

edit: I have tried this but my syntax is way off.

```
requests = (from job in db.JobRequest
                        join jobCode in db.Job on job.JobCode equals jobCode.PkJobCode
                        join jobParams in db.JobRequestParameter on job.PkJobRequestId equals jobParams.FkJobRequestId into jobRequestParameters
                        from jobParams in jobRequestParameters.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                        select new { pkJobRequestId = job, pkJobParameterId = jobParams == null ? false : true} as blahblah 
                        select new Objects.JobRequest.JobRequest()
                        {
                            JobRequestId = job.PkJobRequestId,
                            JobType = job.FkJobType,
                            JobCode = job.JobCode,
                            Schedule = job.Schedule.AddMilliseconds(-job.Schedule.Millisecond),
                            IsRunning = job.Running,
                            Description = jobCode.BriefDescription,
                            HasParameters = blahblah.PkJobParameterId == null ? true : false
                        }).ToList();
```

Comment: What is `job.PkJobRequestId` in your results set? Is it `NULL`? If so, do the same null check like `HasParams = job.PkJobRequestId == null ? true : false` or simply `HasParams = job.PkJobRequestId == null`

Comment: ``HasParams = jobParams?.pkJobParameterId == null``

Comment: @dvo yes it is null

Comment: @Sajid since this is linq I need to be able to access alies jobRequestParameters , then I could check jobRequestParameters.PkJobParameterId == null ? true : false but I can't access jobRequestParameters like this in linq since it is an alias of a left outer join

Comment: @Sajid with this, I get green warning bc type int is never = null. I also cannot make this nullable bc of the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might work, in your original code, to do something like:

```
HasParams = ((object)jobParams.FkJobRequestId) == null
```

But usually when you try to represent LINQ queries as exact translations of their SQL, it ends up overcomplicated. LINQ is a lot more expressive, and can usually represent what you really want better than SQL can. I'd probably do something like this.

```
var requests = (from job in db.JobRequest
                    join jobCode in db.Job on job.JobCode equals jobCode.PkJobCode
                    select new Objects.JobRequest.JobRequest()
                    {
                        JobRequestId = job.PkJobRequestId,
                        JobType = job.FkJobType,
                        JobCode = job.JobCode,
                        Schedule = job.Schedule.AddMilliseconds(-job.Schedule.Millisecond),
                        IsRunning = job.Running,
                        Description = jobCode.BriefDescription,
                        HasParams = db.JobRequestParameter.Any(jobParams => job.PkJobRequestId == jobParams.FkJobRequestId)
                    }).ToList();
```

If you have navigation properties set up on your object model, you can do even better:

```
var requests = (from job in db.JobRequest
                let jobCode = job.JobCodeEntity // or whatever your nav property is called
                select new Objects.JobRequest.JobRequest()
                    {
                        JobRequestId = job.PkJobRequestId,
                        JobType = job.FkJobType,
                        JobCode = job.JobCode,
                        Schedule = job.Schedule.AddMilliseconds(-job.Schedule.Millisecond),
                        IsRunning = job.Running,
                        Description = jobCode.BriefDescription,
                        HasParams = job.JobParams.Any()
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Holy cow! I had no idea you could access tables inside of a select! Thank you!!!!!

Comment: @Jacked_Nerd: Yeah, LINQ is awesome. You may want to check out my update. Also, consider changing your `Objects.JobRequest` namespace: it can cause really annoying problems to have a class in a namespace with the same name as the namespace. Maybe `Objects.JobRequests`?